# Linking position-dependent assembly on Debian

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, clang, x86-64

I'm having trouble linking position-dependent assembly using GCC on Debian 9. The following is the `hello.s` file in assembly:

```
  .section .rodata
hello_str:
  .string "Hello world"
  .text
  .globl main
main:
  xor %rdi, %rdi
  mov $hello_str, %rdi
  call puts      # puts("Hello world");
  xor %rax, %rax # return 0;
  ret
```

Upon running `gcc hello.s`, I receive the following error:

```
$ gcc hello.s
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDvqMUc.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

whereas `clang hello.s` produces an executable:

```
$ clang hello.s
$ file ./a.out 
./a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=ca2f0204d60b5fc197b95c5ccb626a9dfb355a9b, not stripped
$ ./a.out
Hello world
```

When I convert `hello.s` into position-independent code and store it into the `hello-pic.s` file:

```
  .section .rodata
hello_str:
  .string "Hello world"
  .text
  .globl main
main:
  xor %rdi, %rdi
  leaq hello_str(%rip), %rdi
  call puts@PLT  # puts("Hello world");
  xor %rax, %rax # return 0;
  ret
```

then `gcc hello-pic.s` produces an executable (the output of the `file` command and of the produced `a.out` executable is the same as with `clang` for `hello.s`).

I cannot reproduce this issue on other Linux boxes (Ubuntu, CentOS), which leads me to believe that GCC on Debian was build with some non-standard flags. If so, what is the rationale and how can I force GCC to link the position-dependent code? Enclosed is my CPU architecture and related packages that I have currently installed:

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
$ apt list | grep -Ei '(gcc|llvm|clang).*installed'
clang/testing,unstable,now 1:3.8-34+nmu1 amd64 [installed]
clang-3.8/testing,now 1:3.8.1-17 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc/testing,now 4:6.3.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-4.9/stable,now 4.9.2-10 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-4.9-base/stable,now 4.9.2-10 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-5-base/unstable,now 5.4.1-8 amd64 [installed]
gcc-6/testing,now 6.3.0-6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-6-base/testing,now 6.3.0-6 amd64 [installed]
gcc-6-doc/testing,testing,unstable,unstable,now 6.1.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
gcc-6-multilib/testing,now 6.3.0-6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-doc/testing,unstable,now 5:6.1.0-1 amd64 [installed]
gcc-doc-base/testing,testing,unstable,unstable,now 6.1.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
gcc-multilib/testing,now 4:6.3.0-1 amd64 [installed]
lib32gcc-6-dev/testing,now 6.3.0-6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
lib32gcc1/testing,now 1:6.3.0-6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libclang-common-3.8-dev/testing,now 1:3.8.1-17 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libclang1-3.8/testing,now 1:3.8.1-17 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgcc-4.9-dev/stable,now 4.9.2-10 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgcc-5-dev/unstable,now 5.4.1-8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgcc-6-dev/testing,now 6.3.0-6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgcc1/testing,now 1:6.3.0-6 amd64 [installed]
libllvm3.8/testing,now 1:3.8.1-17 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libllvm3.9/testing,now 1:3.9.1-4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libx32gcc-6-dev/testing,now 6.3.0-6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libx32gcc1/testing,now 1:6.3.0-6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-compiler-gcc-6-x86/testing,unstable,now 4.9.13-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
llvm-3.8/testing,now 1:3.8.1-17 amd64 [installed,automatic]
llvm-3.8-dev/testing,now 1:3.8.1-17 amd64 [installed,automatic]
llvm-3.8-runtime/testing,now 1:3.8.1-17 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Comment: Probably one or more of `-fno-pic` , `-fno-PIC` or `-fno-pie`.

Comment: Even `gcc hello.s -no-pie` should work? But I don't have deb9 machine *now* to verify, and some other distro with some gcc 5.x reports it as unknown option, but it can be found in docs, so I'm confused (it does compile your source though, and with `-pie` option it ends with the same error as you have in debian). As the Debian is now set by default to pic/pie, it hopefully understands the opposite options? Try.

Comment: `gcc hello.s -no-pie` does the trick. Why would `-pie` be the default, though?

Comment: For security reasons. ASLR works better with PIE.

Comment: You really should get into the habit of using `leaq hello_str(%rip), %rdi` anyways, since it's shorter and faster.

Answer (score 0):

As other distros Debian 9 seems to enable PIE by default (for security reasons):

```
For the stretch release, the Debian version of the GNU GCC 6 compiler now defaults
to compiling "position independent executables" (PIE).
```

To get old behavior you'll need to add `-no-pie` to `CFLAGS`.